# Phonegap 3.3 resolveLocalFileSystemURI Cannot get Android data/data folder

Tags: android, cordova

I used to be able to run this without problem to get to the databases folder of my Android App:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI('file:///data/data/{package name}/databases', 
        function (entry) {
            alert(entry.fullPath);
        }, rlfsOnErrors);
```

However, the statement returns error when I am using file-transfer plugin v0.4.2. When I switched back to file-transfer plugin v0.3.3, there is no problem. When I am using v0.4.2, I can only gain access to file:///data/media/xxxx directory and not file:///data/data/xxxx.

Anyone has any idea how I can workaround this ? Currently, I am sticking to v0.3.3, but I am sure there is some way to workaround this ?

Thanks.

Comment: try using resolveLocalFileSystemURL instead

Comment: Hi Imran, I have tried resolveLocalFileSystemURL() too, but it gives me error as well.